# ajaxplorer set default language

Tags: ajax, config, explorer, lang, pydio

I use Ajaxplorer as explorater for file on the server I works very fine, but the thing is that I can not, or I do not know how to change default configuration.

In the documentation it s written:

```
Browse to conf and open the file conf.php. Use your favorite text editor to open and modify this document. We’ll customize settings in this file for your unique server configuration and security purposes. Make the mandatory changes listed in section 2.4 Required Settings.

2.4 Required Settings

$dft_langue="en": Set the default language to be used (modify bold portion).
define("ADMIN_PASSWORD", "admin"): Set the administrator password which is granted most permissions (access) on your file server (modify bold portion).
```

I've been looking for the conf.php file since 1 hours but I did not find it.

So I do not know when I do it directly on the interface everytime it says 'your peferences has been saved' but when I close and reopen the window, there is no mora savec configuration.

Of course I've clean the cache after each modification.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Kind regards.

SP.

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to the bootstrap_context.php file that you can find under system_path/ajaxplorer/conf/ folder. If you run into trouble try looking here http://ajaxplorer.info/f/topic/bug-share-center-5-0/